# A regex route does not pass req.params

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following two routes in an Express router:

```
router.get("/v|verses", (req, res) => ...

router.get("/v|verses/:book", (req, res) => ....
```

Why does an invocation of `/verses/john` route to the first one with `req.params` an empty object?

It works fine if I don't use a regular expression but have separate routes for `/v` and `/verses`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change to the following `/v(?:|erses)?/:book`.

From the Express documentation:

> Express uses [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) for matching the route paths; see the path-to-regexp documentation for all the possibilities in defining route paths. [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/) is a handy tool for testing basic Express routes, although it does not support pattern matching.

When `/v|verses/:book` is evaluated through the Express Route Tester tool, the resulting regex is `/^\/v\|verses\/((?:[^\/]+?))(?:\/(?=$))?$/i` which will fail due to the way the alteration is used - the regex says, to *either* patch something that starts with `^\/v\` (a plain `/v`) **OR** ends with `verses\/((?:[^\/]+?))(?:\/(?=$))` (basically `verses/<anything>`).

The alteration goes in order and it matches the first thing it finds, so for So with input of "**/v**erses/john" in only matches the first alteration and not the second. You can also [see this on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7xWvyJ/1).

One thing that you need to keep in mind is that Express uses an *old* version of the path-to-regexp library - the Express dependency is `0.1.7` whereas the current package version is `6.1.0`. I'm not sure why Express is not using a newer version - the older one doesn't seem to fully support some groupings, so it produces invalid regular expression for them.

One option was to pass in a regular expression directly, so you *could* go for `app.get(/^\/(?:v\|verses)\/((?:[^\/]+?))(?:\/(?=$))?$/, (req, res) => {})` - similar to what SHOULD be generated but done by hand. However, it's not readable and you don't get the mapping of `req.params.book`, you just get.

Another option is to supply an array of paths: `app.get(['/verses/:book', '/v/:book'], (req, res) => {})`. This is valid way to map multiple paths. If you wish you could go with that.

Finally, however to fix the syntax, you need `/v(?:|erses)?/:book` - a `v` optionally followed by `erses` or nothing in a non-capturing group. If you use a normal capturing group, then `/verses/john` produces `req.params` of type: `{0: erses, book: john}`. So, with this, you get the correct pattern here `/^\/((?:v|verses))\/((?:[^\/]+?))(?:\/(?=$))?$/i`. [See on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/t9fNrh/1).

Comment: Using `/(v|verses)/:book` results in `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/(?(?:([^\/]+?))|verses)\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/: Invalid group`

Comment: Odd. I get this in the Express Route Tester but only for package version 0.1.7. Perhaps that's what express uses internally? Let me check if there is a way to do it there.

Comment: OK...found a way around it. And Express is indeed using a SUPER OLD version being 0.1.7. The newer versions of that `path-to-regexp` library do support syntax better but that one for some reason dislikes certain groupings. I can't really figure out why and the documentation from version 0.1.7 is a bit lacking. So, I did the best I can. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just learned that the regex applies to the whole path string.